# Synchronizing a file system (syncfs) in Go

Tags: go, filesystems, synchronization

Is there a package that exports the [`syncfs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sync.2.html) function in Go? I'd like to synchronize a particular file system.

I found the [syscall](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/) package, but it only exports `FSync`, `Fdatasync` and `Sync`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`syncfs` is just a system call, which are easy to trigger in Go.

However, since the [`syscall` package](https://godoc.org/syscall) does not have the `syncfs` syscall constant, you can use [`golang.org/x/sys/unix`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/unix) instead, which has it defined (not really necessity, since a syscall constant is just a number, but using that package doesn't hurt).

```
import "golang.org/x/sys/unix"

func syncfs(fd int) error {
    _, _, err := unix.Syscall(unix.SYS_SYNCFS, uintptr(fd), 0, 0)
    if err != 0 {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

For completeness, here is the solution just using the `syscall` package:

```
import "syscall"

func syncfs(fd int) error {
    _, _, err := syscall.Syscall(306, uintptr(fd), 0, 0)
    if err != 0 {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```